# Gparted : Resize (split) Primary Partition?

Tags: partition, gparted, trisquel

This is my current partition table:

[image: screen0]

In which `/dev/sda8` is the partition on Which I am currently running my primary OS - [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) GNU/Linux (you can see it's mount point as `/`). The `/dev/sda1` is the primary partition containing Windows XP.

I want to resize `/dev/sda1` (Size:50GB ; Used 27.97GB) i.e. want to reduce it to 30GB (Split into 30GB + 20GB). So, I've first Unmounted `/dev/sda1`.

Now When I use **Resize/Move** option (from right-click menu) The following window appears:

[image: screen1]

The **problem** is that it doesn't allow to reduce partition! Why?(Because it is primary partition?)

And Finally **How can I  resize (reduce/split) `/dev/sda1`?**

Note:- Gparted is running from Trisquel (GNU/Linux).

Comment: The reason you can't downsize the partition is probably because you have un-movable files in it. You need to log on to your Windows system and remove any system restore points and disable swap (virtual memory) on this partition. After one or two reboots, you should be able to perform the resize.

Comment: This might be an issue with Linux in general and Gparted in particular being not particularly friendly with NTFS/Windows partitions. You might want to try using MiniTools Partition Wizard - it is a tool for Windows that is generally similar in operation and capabilities to Gparted.

Comment: Use a Windows defrag program to move all files to the beginning of the partition.

Comment: @frostschutz Finally Defragmentation helped me! Now I can Resize partition by using Gparted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can resize any ntfs based partition, you need to ensure all the files are pushed up to the start of the partition. This is acomplisehd by running the defragmentation process on the partition within windowsXP.
It may also be useful to delete any temporal files or any other stuff you don't want from the windows partition.
In addition, deleting the windows swap file may also be helpfull, as it is normally not moved by the defragmentation tool. You can safely delete the pagefile from linux before resizing the partition, or you may turn off the swap file within windows.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Windows XP places a master file table at the end of the partition, preventing you from resizing it. You should be able to move the master file table from within XP. Also maybe you need to defrag the Windows partition? And finally, are you sure you unmounted sda1? Run `df` in a terminal and make sure you don't see /dev/sda1 anywhere in the output, then close and reopen GParted

Answer (score 0):

Try running a chkdsk and/or scandisk in Windows [to rule out bad sectors & other inconcistencies] then attempt to resize.